# How to get file pointer value without moving to next file pointer location (in C)

Tags: c, pointers, file-io

Is there a way to find the character stored in file pointer without fgetc.
Say I have a word "steve jobs" in a file called apple.txt is there something like

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
  {
   FILE *fp=fopen("apple.txt","r");
   if(fp=='s'&&(fp+2)=='e')
     printf("steve is there");
   else
     printf("Steve not there");
   fclose(fp);
  }
```

Clearly this doesn't really work! It just prints something like C forbids comparison b/n pointer n int. Even i tried adding * in front of (fp+2) and fp, it said no match for operator==

I believe the function fgetc(FILE *) works in such a way that it gets the unsigned char and then moves the pointer to the next location. Is there any function to just get the character without moving the pointer and also is the above code possible in any other way?!

Comment: I would suggest perhaps a tutorial on file IO. Your question is fairly nonsensical; `fp` is a *file descriptor*. You would need to read ahead using any of the IO fuctions to do so, then `fseek` back to your starting position.

Comment: Your question says "no match for operator==", but you tagged it C.  What's up with that?

Comment: actually i'm using Code Blocks.. but yeah it did say that! after all i was using stdio.h library file. That means C right :D

Comment: He wants C code but is compiling as C++.  @user997147: `stdio.h` is in both languages.

Comment: @BrianRoach That's not completely correct. `fp` is not a file descriptor, but a `FILE` struct holding lots of metadata, including the current position of read/write heads and crucially, a pointer to a buffer. Libc does some implicit readahead when you open or read a file, and so it may very well be possible to do what he is asking. I'm not saying anything about portability or maintainability, however!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use `getc` and **`ungetc`**. Read the documentation about it (you can only have one push-back character).

On some systems (notably Posix systems like Linux) you have the ability to map into memory a portion of a file. Read more about the [`mmap` system call](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) which enables you to see a portion of a file as segment of memory. (`mmap` is not usable on non-seekable files like pipes or sockets; it basically works mostly on "disk" files).

Comment: wow.. this helps. The ungetc thingy was what I was searching for. Thanks. And i'll take a look at mmap too. Thanks a lot

Comment: Beware that you can only call ungetc once for every character gotten with getc. But some systems or libraries (perhaps Glibc on Linux) might sometimes give you more. I won't depend on that behavior. And of course, some files (but not all, e.g. not a socket or a pipe) are seekable, with fseek and ftell

Comment: Clarification: you can only call ungetc once *in between* any pair of read operations.  Or it is perhaps better to say (as you did in your original answer) that you can only ungetc one character at any given time.

Answer (score 4):

"The character stored in file pointer" is not a meaningful thing to ask for.  There aren't necessarily any characters *stored* in a `FILE`.  For instance, `stdin` and `stdout` are often communication channels rather than files on the disk, and they may not be doing any buffering at all.

What you can do instead, if you *know* a `FILE` refers to an actual file on the disk rather than a communications channel, is read a few characters and then use `fseek` to move back to where you were before you read them.  Your example program, rewritten to do that, would look something like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("orange.txt", "r")
    if (!fp)
    {
        perror("fopen(orange.txt)");
        return 1;
    }

    if (getc(fp) == 'b' &&
        getc(fp) == 'a' &&
        getc(fp) == 'n' &&
        getc(fp) == 'a' &&
        getc(fp) == 'n' &&
        getc(fp) == 'a')
        puts("orange has a banana");
    else
        puts("orange has no bananas");

    /* return to the beginning of the file */
    if (fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET))
    {
        perror("fseek(orange.txt)");
        return 1;
    }

    /* do something else with `fp` here */

    /* all files are automatically closed on exit */
    return 0;
}
```

If you're working with a file whose nature you don't know, though -- such as *any* file given to you by the user -- you have to be prepared for `fseek` to fail and set `errno` to `ESPIPE`, which means "that's not a file, that's a data stream, you can't jump around in it".